# Can I put analytics script in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, performance

When we get different script, like for google analytics, adsense, or facebook code etc, generally there are 2 scripts.

The first one is an external script tag and the second one some javascript code.

My question: Which is the best way to include these scripts (performance-related)?

I was thinking of including

```
<script src="//analytics.com/" async defer></script>"`
```

in `<head>` , and the js code in a js file, say, `main.js`, so that it can be cached and minimized with the rest of the javascript.

Would there be any disadvantages of doing this?

If not, (if this is actually better), why everybody is suggesting to put the scripts inside `<body>` ?

Comment: Generally speaking, writing scripts before the closing `</body>` tag is the best for performance. In this case, I would just follow the recommendations from Google or Facebook. You can also use Google Tag Manager which will load the tags asynchronously and will be quite fast.

Comment: @SamCreamer Why is it better performance when including these kind of scripts in footer (before </body>) instead of a .js file?

Comment: You can put them in a `.js` file, just include them at the bottom before the end of the body (ie: `<script src="wtvr.js" />`) right before the closing body tag. It is faster because it will load the html elements on the page before loading the javascript. This will cause the user to be able to physically see the page while the js loads (especially if there is a big library to import).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just answer the question:

## yes.

Is it better?

Well, kind of. It will be cached, minimized , which is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple 3rd-party scripts its easier to use [Google Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en) to handle this for you. You add the tag manager script to your page, and it takes care of injecting whatever you want.